# Remove embedded and inline css from ajax response?

Tags: jquery

How to remove embedded and inline css from ajax response using jQuery? Is there is a way to filter the css from ajax response?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this peice of Jquery to remove any known style from the element.

```
$(element).removeAttr('style');​ /*this will remove any inline style from the element.*/
```

Comment: this lacks some explanation and answers only part of the question. what about embedded css-blocks?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post("someURL",data, function(response){
   var newElement = $(response).removeAttr("style");
   $("#someContainer").append(newElement);
})
```